# Setting file permissions using Rake

Tags: file, permissions, rake

I'd like to set the file permissions for a copied file using a rake task.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use File class:
[File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002550)

Comment: Other related things to look at: FileUtils, Dir, Find